# Repetitive value assignment with computation

Tags: javascript, typescript, non-repetitive

I have some TS code that I'm not happy with. I'im doing three times the same thing. How could this be cleaner?

A position object has an x, y and z axis that can be set with position.x = ... or give it all the values with position.set(x,y,z).

Could I use a sort of map function that goes over all the values and assigns a new value based on some computation.

```
private moveTowardsCamera(camera: THREE.Camera) {
        this.children.forEach((child: Asteroid) => {
            child.position.set(
                child.position.x += (camera.position.x - child.position.x) * this.speed,
                child.position.y += (camera.position.y - child.position.y) * this.speed,
                child.position.z += (camera.position.z - child.position.z) * this.speed  
            );
            child.rotation.set(
                child.rotation.x += this.rotationIncrement,
                child.rotation.y += this.rotationIncrement,
                child.rotation.z += this.rotationIncrement
            );
        });
    }
```

Comment: What is the `.set` method? It looks extremely strange to be passing an argument *and* reassigning `child.position.#` in the same statement. Can you do, for example, `child.position.set(  child.position.x + (camera.position.x - child.position.x) * this.speed`, will that work as well?

Comment: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Vector3 maybe I could use Vector3.fromArray in a way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over an array of `['x', 'y', 'z']`, map it, and spread it into the different `.set` calls:

```
// make sure to use `as const` here so the type doesn't get widened to Array<string>
const dims = ['x', 'y', 'z'] as const;
private moveTowardsCamera(camera: THREE.Camera) {
    this.children.forEach((child: Asteroid) => {
        child.position.set(
            ...(dims.map(dim => 
                child.position[dim] + (camera.position[dim] - child.position[dim]) * this.speed
            ) as [number, number, number])
        );
        child.rotation.set(
            ...(dims.map(dim => 
                child.rotation[dim] + this.rotationIncrement
            ) as [number, number, number])
        );
    });
}
```

Pretty sure you should be calling the `.set` method with the new vector values instead of reassigning the `child.position` or `child.rotation` values at the same time that you call `.set`.

Comment: TypeScript is complaining TS2556: Expected 3-4 arguments, but got 0 or more.

Comment: It doesn't like the spreading, that's unfortunate, I guess you can use `as` to specify the length of the mapped array